# First contact book where humans, humanoid cat people and other aliens are captured to fight for their alien captors

Tags: story-identification, books, first-contact

Humans are captured, transported to an alien starship, then brutally trained to fight by fighting each other. Ultimately a leader emerges and his trained team is then introduced to other captured alien teams. One of the other alien teams are humaniod cat people, who the human leader wins a female fighter of the cat team. Eventually all teams unite, finally fight their captors, take over the starbase to make their way to other alien planets on their way back to earth.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  What did the cover look like?  Was it part of a series?  Are the captives used as soldiers or as gladiators?

Comment: Hi, I can't remember when I read it, maybe around 3 years ago and I am not sure if it was new at the time of audio release. Nor can I remember the cover, it may have been a series and the captives are soldiers, captive Mercs if you will.

Comment: One of the mid 90's SFBC selections was like this. The aliens were caled the"Masters". I'll see if I can dig it out of a box.

Comment: I think it was written between 2000 and 3016.

Comment: Typo, should be 2016